# Clean SOLR routing in TYPO3 v10 with filter, search query and pagination

Tags: routes, solr, typo3-10.x

I am having a hard time writing the routing.yaml for our solr instance in a TYPO3 v10 installation. We are running apache-solr-for-typo3/solr: 11.2.1

The URLs are

- http://localhost/search/?q=mysearchquery
- http://localhost/search/?tx_solr%5Bpage%5D=2&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=mysearchquery
- http://localhost/search/tx_solr%5Bfilter%5D%5B0%5D=type%3AMYTYPEVALUE&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=mysearchquery
- http://localhost/search/tx_solr%5Bfilter%5D%5B0%5D=type%3AMYTYPEVALUE&tx_solr%5Bpage%5D=2&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=mysearchquery

Where i want:

- type to be just /type/ in the url
- q to be just / if possible
- page to be /p/

I've looked at https://docs.typo3.org/p/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/11.1/en-us/Routing/ConfigureRouting.html and this works for the type filtering, but it breaks when trying to enter a search query incombination with it.

I couldn't find a complete example online or in slacks channels. So a correct answer here might help alot of other in the future.